# Getting sockaddr_in from CFDataRef

Tags: objective-c, network-programming

I have a CFDataRef (I am not even sure, why I use CFData and Socket anymore..) which contains a clients address (a struct sockaddr_in) and I need to get the IP and port. Unfortunately there are no direct methods to get them.

Hence I have tried the following:

```
CFDataRef clientAddress = ...; //defined somewhere else, contains a sockaddr_in
struct sockaddr_in clientAddress2;
clientAddress2 = *(struct sockaddr_in*)CFDataGetBytePtr(clientAddress);
```

(don't take the names to seriously, they are just for the purpose of this example).
Unfortuantely the execution of CFDataGetBytePtr seems to crash, since I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x0)" error, when running my app.

What is the best way to get the IP and Port from a CFDataRef containing a sockaddr_in?

Thank you!

Comment: im not sure why uour are going down to that level either :) but see my answer

Comment: CFDataGetBytePtr doesnt copy the bytes so they are freed with the data.. maybe that is your problem? the struct points to memory freed

Comment: well, CFSocket was the best I could find to realize a UDP connection. However it seems like when using them, you need to get back to C level very quickly and even have to transform in both directions :-( Not sure if I get what you're saying. Why does it free the data? The documentation does not say anything about that. Still can't figure out the correct solution..

Comment: CFDataRef frees its bytes when the CFDataRef is deallocated
then the socket_addr* becomes a pointer to garbage

Answer (score 3):

You can convert **CFDataRef** to **NSData**, than assign **BYTES** to structure **sockaddr**.

If the address could be IP6 or IP4 you check the INET FAMILY and than assign the **BYTES** to the correct structure (**sockaddr_in** for IP4 or **sockaddr_in6** for IP6)

For example, assume that **address** is value of type **CFDataRef address**

```
    NSString *addressString;
    int port=0;
    struct sockaddr *addressGeneric;
    struct sockaddr_in addressClient;

    NSData *myData = (__bridge NSData *)address;
    addressGeneric = (struct sockaddr *) [myData bytes];

    switch( addressGeneric->sa_family ) {
        case AF_INET: {
          struct sockaddr_in *ip4;
          char dest[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
          ip4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) [myData bytes];
          port = ntohs(ip4->sin_port);
          addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"IP4: %s Port: %d", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ip4->sin_addr, dest, sizeof dest),port];
         }
         break;

        case AF_INET6: {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ip6;
            char dest[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
            ip6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) [myData bytes];
            port = ntohs(ip6->sin6_port);
            addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"IP6: %s Port: %d",  inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &ip6->sin6_addr, dest, sizeof dest),port];
         }
         break;
       default:
         addressString=@"Error on get family type.";
         break;
     }

     NSLog(@"Client Address: %@",addressString);
```

This is the output

2013-08-25 12:22:35.308 FGWakeService[9283:303] **Client Address: IP4: 192.168.69.38 Port: 58614**